# Any way to run an external process on node.js and wait for his "return"?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

i have been looking for some days after this in order to avoid writting again a lot of code i already have in C language.
Is any way of running an external program, that i already has coded on C, obviously giving some parameters that it need to accomplish some task and then get the "return" variable? All that is for a lil home proyect i am making.
I am looking for making this on node.js just cause its the framework i am using for getting my backend done.
First question i made on a long time, only making it because i am not finding out it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options in the nodejs [`child_process` module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).  Some of those options will "wait" and run the external program synchronously such as `execFileSync()`, `execSync()` and `spawnSync()`.  But, keep in mind that if you do that, your entire node.js process is blocked while waiting.  You would never want to do that in a server that needs to be responsive to incoming requests, but could do it other types of scripts.

Also, you don't have to use the synchronous versions.  You can still run the program and get the results, just doing so asynchronously where you'll get notified when it completes.

Comment: Ty man, i will continue researching on that module, exactly that things is what i need. Its a really tiny server and does not get too much requests at the same time to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Given that main programs in C can only return an integer value (a `0` or non-zero byte) indicating the exit status of the app: running the the app in a child process with node's [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) or [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and printing the value of the variables you wish to return to standard output (with a function like [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)) will allow you to capture and use them in node.

For example, in an `example.js` file you can run the executable file you compiled, pass in a parameter as a string via [`argv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html), and return a promise. By making your server `async`, it will allow the node process to `await` the return value of your program and handle its success or failures asynchronously:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const http = require('http')
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const hostname = '127.0.0.1'
const port = '3000'

const execCProgram = (parameter) => {
  return new Promise((resolved, rejected) => {
    exec(`./example ${parameter}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        rejected(error);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }

    const cData = {returnValue: stdout};

    resolved(cData);
    });
  })
}

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  await execCProgram('JS_DATA').then(data => {
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.end(`My data in node: ${data.returnValue}\n`)
  });
})

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
})
```

Example C program this runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *mutated_parameter = strcat(argv[argc - 1], " that was mutated in my C program and returned");
  printf("%s", mutated_parameter);

  return 0;
}
```

If the `return` value is anything other than 0, the promise from `example.js` will throw.

Example Client-side Output:

```
$ curl localhost:3000
My data in node: JS_Data that was mutated in my C program and returned
```

> Note: consider using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) or [`spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) if your app is going to run for a while and generate a lot of output data.

Comment: Question is "Any way to run an external process on node.js and wait for his “return”?". So, does your `exec(`./example ${parameter}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => { ... });` is synchronous call. Another words, will it wait for return?

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem. I am not looking for the C program to make a console print or anything like that. I need the return of the C program to know if i get an error on the process or whatever.

Comment: Ah, ok! Well, if you wrap your `exec` function in a `promise`, and your server in an `async` function – you can capture the success or failure of the C process. Example error: 

`error: Command failed: ./example JS_DATA (node:5000)`

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: ./example JS_DATA`

I'll go ahead an update the example I wrote above accordingly. 